# Will my US 120v power tools work on UK 240v 50Hz?

Tags: electrical

I may be moving to Scotland for my wife's job. Will my power tools and other basic electrical equipment (like fans and lights) work on 240v 50Hz?

Answer (score 4):

#### Probably not, but check the specs.

A lot of consumer electronics - e.g., computers, TVs, etc. will work fine on a range of 90V - 240V and 50/60 hz. That is because they are designed to work that way and a key is that most of those electronics actually work on **DC** power. So they build in a power supply that converts high voltage AC to low voltage DC. Frequency doesn't matter (within reason) because the result is DC = no frequency at all. Voltage doesn't matter (within reason) because there are components that can handle a wide range and 90 -> 5 or 240 -> 5 is a big change either way.

However, motors are a different story. If a motor runs directly on AC then it will be dependent on the voltage and the frequency in a number of ways, and rewiring (or possibly even redesign) is needed to run correctly (and safely) with 2x voltage and/or 50 instead of 60 hz frequency.

**Check the specifications or the nameplate** and you should be able to figure it out easily enough. The frequency is a particular issue with motors, so even if you use a transformer to go from 240V to 120V, the motor may still not work correctly, leading to it running too slowly and/or premature wear.

Battery operated tools are a little different. Since they run off batteries, the only issue is the charger. Battery chargers are often designed to handle 90 - 240 & 50/60, just like laptop computer power packs. But check the specs to be sure.

Comment: Check the specs. Bloody true. It is slightly easier to accomodate 230V/50Hz circuits to 110V/60Hz than vice versa. My camera charger is 230/110VAC compliant while the "same" charger sold in the US is only 110VAC compliant.

Comment: @Crowley As easy to go one way as the other. The issue is costs & market share. The US/Canada market is **huge** for a lot of products. So many items will be specifically for US (i.e., 120V/60Hz/English packaging) with often just adding Spanish (because of the number of people here speaking Spanish plus compatibility of 120V/60Hz with much of Central/South America) and French (to satisfy Canadian laws). The same companies will make a "universal" model 120/240, 50/60, lots of languages in the instructions to sell "everywhere else". But this way they save $1 on each one in the US, which adds up.

Comment: Parts that can survive higher voltages are "just" oversized when used on lower voltages, but has to face higher currents on the input though. 60Hz transformers can be slightly lighter than their 50Hz counterparts. This leads, as you say, in cost/market share favouring US-only devices in the US market and their "universal" counterparts in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

I also moved to Scotland from the US (since moved back) and faced the same problem. Most of my electronics were not designed to work on 240/50Hz and so we had to buy replacements. However for my desk top computer, I bought a very good convertor that plugged into the Scottish 240/50Hz and gave me a very clean 120/60Hz. The converter was a good one and cost me several hundred dollars (pounds) but was certainly cheaper than a new computer. The cheap convertors (

PS Scotland was wonderful for us, my first son born there!

Comment: With a computer the power supply will often have a switch at the back you can turn over. Or a drop-in replacement for just the PSU is easily found for just as much as that converter.

Comment: @ratchetfreak As I said in my answer: *A lot of consumer electronics - e.g., computers, TVs, etc. will work fine on a range of 90V - 240V and 50/60 hz.* The problem these days is generally NOT the computers, it is anything with a motor (fans, drills & other tools) and anything with a heating element (heater, toaster, hair dryer).

Answer (score 2):

### Look at the kit the UK requires at *work sites*

In the UK, cheap consumer tools are 240V and quality commercial tools are 110V. *Say what?*

The UK requires very special power on *work sites*, to reduce the risk of electric shock to workers.  This is **110V** (really) *with a center ground*. That means each "hot" leg is only 55 volts away from earth.  This is provided by special transformers that workmen hook up at the work sites.  They are readily available.

Sadly, they did not use NEMA 5-15 as their receptacle type, so you will need to buy or make some cheater cords to get you from UK construction sockets to USA NEMA 5-15.

Motors that run at constant speed, such as for a compressor, may not be happy running 50Hz, and may run hotter.  Less of a problem on handheld power tools.

Cheat-plugging a 120V or 110V appliance straight into common UK wall 240V is right out, unless the tool's instructions or labeling specifically say that's OK.  Avoid hokey-dokey cheap Cheese adapters which advertise 110V conversion or claim to fit.... Buy stuff like that from reputable local shops, Wickes is the lowest you should stoop.